# Log AWS Lambda events from multiple functions into one tidy place

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have about a dozen aws lambda functions written in python. Each does its thing and logs what happens to CloudWatch Logs. that works fine, however it is tedious to parse through the logs for each of the lambdas as i make them very detailed for debugging.

What i would like to do is have a 'master log'. One log file for all of the lambdas (in addition to the cloudwatch one for each). this master log would aggregate all of the ***critical*** messages from all of the lambdas and leave out the mundane fluff.

Where and how are (is?) the best way to get this done?

I can use boto3 but it looks like S3 files are not really made to be appended to - they are meant to be replaced. that could be messy with 12 lambdas logging to it at once.

Perhaps could i use boto with cloudwatch logs?

Comment: One way is use logstash.  Either create you own logstash stack using EC2 or other aWS resources, e.g. : 
http://devblog.springest.com/complete-logstash-stack-on-aws-opsworks-in-15-minutes

Comment: My way: I provide a exclusive POST resource (and its http client in nodejs), so, on each function i call some thing similar to: logme("some","thing"). This method is incorporated into each of your lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda configures the logging for you automatically and it doesn't look like there is a way to customize which log group or log stream is used.

I haven't tried it but it seems like you could pass in your own log group and log stream to your handler, either as parameters to the handler or as environment variables.  Then you could use something like [watchtower](https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower/tree/master/watchtower) to configure your own logging handler so all of your functions write to the same place.